# Is it possible to link transaction line items to sale transaction in Square pos API

Tags: square-connect, square, pos

I understand that the Square POS API does not currently support the ability for an external app to pass itemized line items when calling Square to process the payment. Is there a way for the external app to associate the itemized details with the completed sale transaction in Square via an API after the payment is completed and square returns control to the external app?

Are there specific plans to provide support for itemized transactions within the POS API?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to formally do this currently, and there's no current timeline or guarantee that it will be released for the POS API.

It's possible to link it via the `Orders` API in a workaround. Basically, prior to initializing the transaction, you would call `CreateOrder` with the items in the order. The response would give you an `Order` object, which you can retrieve the `order_id` from. Then, you can pass in the `order_id` into the `notes` field when creating the POS API request. This would allow you to at least look up the itemization later on (by utilizing `BatchRetrieveOrders`) for each of the POS API transactions.

Furthermore, if you are going further and utilizing your own database, then you wouldn't even need to pass in the `order_id` to the note field, as you could just link the `order_id` and `transaction_id` in your own database for easy lookup later.

References:
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/more-apis/orders/overview
https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#navsection-orders

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that if I am unable to link the line items in the order to the Square sales transaction, the item detail will not be available to the Square reports and I will not be able to get itemized sales breakdowns. Is there anyway to solve that problem?

Comment: In for comments. I'm trying to pass the items DB ID from our server to the API and retrieve it on the callback to update the line item as paid. So far I'm unable to do so

Comment: @MikeMoore Did you find a way now ? I am looking for the exact use case as per your comment. I need to list external transactions onto Square reports for consolidating sale metrics.

Comment: @JayanthRamachandran no, I had to switch to Shopify